# How Pick function work when data is not a list?

Tags: functions, filtering

This is from the Document center.

```
In[548]:= Pick[f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, 1]

Out[548]= f[1, 3, 5, 6]
```

Can anyone explain how this work when data is not a list?

> **Pick**[list,sel,patt] 
> picks out those elements of list for which the corresponding element of sel matches patt.

How do they determine corresponding element when they aren't the same type? Also not even a list?

**EDIT**: Do they rely on level to determine corresponding element? How about this case?

```
sel = {1, Cos[1], Sin[1]}; 
list = {a, b, f[b]}; 
Pick[list, sel, 1]
```

Why is the output `{a, f[b]}` not `{a, b}`because only `1` in `Sin[1]` matches the pattern instead?

Comment: I read that already but still not clear how do they determine corresponding element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation page says "The heads in *list* and *sel* do not have to be List."

Any heads will work, e.g. `Pick[f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], x[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], 1]` (unless `f` or `x` evaluate to something incompatible).

The first, third, fifth and sixth elements of *sel* (or `x`) are 1s, as specified by *patt*, so those are the elements of `f` picked.

***Addition to the OP's question***

```
sel = {1, Cos[1], Sin[1]}; 
list = {a, b, f[b]}; 
Pick[list, sel, 1]
```

> ```
> {a, f[b]}
> ```

The documentation says for this case (in Properties & Relations): The comparison in Pick[*list*, *sel*, *patt* ] is purely structural, with no regard to heads.

An argument in *sel* containing 1 is matched to the argument in *list*.

```
Pick[{f[a], b, f[b, c]}, {Sin[0], Cos[1], x[0, 1]}, 1]
```

> ```
> {f[c]}
> ```

Comment: Do they rely on level to determine corresponding element? 
How about this case? `sel = {1, Cos[1], Sin[1]}; list = {a, b, f[b]}; Pick[list, sel, 1]` why the output is `{a, f[b]}` not `{a, b}`?